# Running balance in Mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

**MySQL DB Table**

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
    (`id` int, `e_id` int, `l_id` int, `amt` int, `type` varchar(2), `date` datetime)
;
    
INSERT INTO table_name
    (`id`, `e_id`,`l_id`, `amt`, `type`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 10, 70000, 'Dr', '2022-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (2, 1, 11,  8000, 'Dr', '2022-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (3, 1, 12, 78000, 'Cr', '2022-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (4, 2, 10, 90000, 'Dr', '2022-02-01 00:00:00'),
    (5, 2, 11, 2000, 'Dr', '2022-02-01 00:00:00'),
    (6, 2, 12, 92000, 'Cr', '2022-02-01 00:00:00'),
    (7, 3, 13, 50000, 'Cr', '2022-03-01 00:00:00'),
    (8, 3, 14, 2000, 'Cr', '2022-03-01 00:00:00'),
    (9, 3, 15, 52000, 'Dr', '2022-03-01 00:00:00')
;
```

**MySQL Query**

```
select id, 
case when `type` = 'Dr' then `amt` else 0 end as Dr,
case when `type` = 'Cr' then `amt` else 0 end as Cr,
date,
sum(case when `type` = 'Dr' then -`amt` when `type` = 'Cr' then `amt` end) over(order by date rows unbounded preceding) as balance

from table_name
WHERE l_id=12
  ;
```

I would like to get the following output

```
id  |  Dr     |  Cr      |    date    | balance         
----+---------+----------+------------+--------
 1  |   70000 |    0     | 01-01-2022 | 70000
 2  |    8000 |    0     | 01-01-2022 | 78000
 4  |   90000 |    0     | 02-01-2022 | 168000
 5  |    2000 |    0     | 02-01-2022 | 170000
```

My query needs to consider all `e_id` values where `l_id` = 12 except where `l_id` = 12 (ignoring id's 3 and 6).

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do, can you add more details ?

Comment: So, `where l_id <> 12` instead of `where l_id = 12`. But why don't the results use IDs 7,8, or 9?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I want to bring the e_id results where l_id is =12

Comment: I don't understand "needs to consider where l_id = 12 except where l_id = 12". You seem to be contradicting yourself.

Comment: To calculate a running total you’d need to use a window function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

Comment: @NickW They *are* using a window function. Scroll to the right.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I want to bring the e_id results where l_id is =12 except for the result where l_id = 12.  For example IDs 1,2,3 have the same e_id and IDs 4,5,6 have the same e_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this :

```
select id,
case when `type` = 'Dr' then `amt` else 0 end as Dr,
case when `type` = 'Cr' then `amt` else 0 end as Cr,
date,
sum(case when `type` = 'Dr' then `amt` when `type` = 'Cr' then `amt` end) over(order by date rows unbounded PRECEDING ) as balance

from table_name
WHERE e_id in (select e_id from table_name where l_id=12 ) and l_id <> 12 ;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/x4GM4vIB)